# How do I allocate resources for a UITableViewCell without creating creating memory leaks

Tags: uitableview, avplayer

I have a UITableView the I'm adding cell to. Each cell contains an image, a title, and a AVPlayer. I'm implementing as follows

```c
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"MyCell";
    VideoFeedCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        NSArray *topLevelObjects = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"MyCell" owner:self options:nil];
        cell = [topLevelObjects objectAtIndex:0];
    }
    NSDictionary *row = [myobj  objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    AVURLAsset *asset = [AVURLAsset URLAssetWithURL:url options:nil];
    AVPlayerItem *playerItem = [AVPlayerItem playerItemWithAsset:asset];
    AVPlayer *player = [AVPlayer playerWithPlayerItem:playerItem];
    AVPlayerLayer *playerLayer = [AVPlayerLayer playerLayerWithPlayer:player];
    playerLayer.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 300.0, 300.0);       
    player.actionAtItemEnd = AVPlayerActionAtItemEndNone;
    [cell.myViewContainer.layer addSublayer:playerLayer];
    return cell
}
```

I'm concerned for a number of reasons, creating an AVPlayer for each cell seems like it would eat allot of memory. I'm also not clear how dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier works. If I Throw an NSLog in the middle of this, it gets called every time I scroll up and down, which leads me to believe I creating a new instance of AVPlayer as well, and this seams like a giant memory leak. Basically, how to I do this correctly, allocate a class (like a AVPlayer) for use in a UITableviewCell, but make sure that I don't re-allocate it the next time cellForRowAtIndexPath is called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put any alloc code inside the `if (cell == nil)` block. So taking your code, try this:

```c
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"MyCell";
    VideoFeedCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        NSArray *topLevelObjects = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"MyCell" owner:self options:nil];
        cell = [topLevelObjects objectAtIndex:0];
        AVURLAsset *asset = [AVURLAsset URLAssetWithURL:url options:nil];
        AVPlayerItem *playerItem = [AVPlayerItem playerItemWithAsset:asset];
        AVPlayer *player = [AVPlayer playerWithPlayerItem:playerItem];
        AVPlayerLayer *playerLayer = [AVPlayerLayer playerLayerWithPlayer:player];
        playerLayer.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 300.0, 300.0);       
        player.actionAtItemEnd = AVPlayerActionAtItemEndNone;
        [cell.myViewContainer.layer addSublayer:playerLayer];
    }
    NSDictionary *row = [myobj  objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    return cell
}
```

Comment: I ran the code, but the problem is, it only creates two distinct cells (which actually makes sense). Since, I'm alos allocating my AVPlayerAsset only when a new cell is created, The cells repeat with the same AVAsset over and over again.

Comment: Outside of the "if (cell == nil)", you need to set the new playerItem for the player. Use "[player replaceCurrentItemWithPlayerItem:newItem]"

Answer (score 0):

You can clean unnecessary instances:

```
-(void)prepareForReuse{
    [super prepareForReuse];
    [playerLayer removeFromSuperlayer];
    playerLayer = nil;
    playerItem = nil;
    asset = nil;
    player = nil;
}
```